# pinescript how to make a vertical line everytime it goes over or under zero

Tags: pine-script

cheers.

Just a simple question, but not sure it's possible and not sure how to work with vline properly.

```
//@version=4
study("Distance to MA")

len=input(200, title="Length", type=input.integer)
src=input(close, title="Source", type=input.source)
siglen=input(1, title="Signal Length", type=input.integer)
ma=ema(src,len)
dist=src-ma
plot(dist, style=plot.style_columns)
sig = ema(dist,siglen)
sigclr = sig>sig[1]?color.green:color.red
plot(sig, color=sigclr, transp=1, linewidth=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay=true)

len=input(200, title="Length", type=input.integer)
src=input(close, title="Source", type=input.source)
siglen=input(1, title="Signal Length", type=input.integer)
ma=ema(src,len)
dist=src-ma

someCondition = dist < 0

if someCondition
    line.new(bar_index, 0, bar_index, 1, extend=extend.both)
```

Comment: my brother! legend wait for it

Comment: does this just kind of getit in proximity of the ema?

Comment: also looks like it doesnt really go as far back as woukld like? wonder why that changed all of a sudden ... only gets about 200 bars of data

Comment: maybe is there way to not make it onto the chart and just leave it as an oscillator indicator or that not possible... think mabye thats what fkn with chart